# How to pass generic field to observable collection

Tags: c#, generics

I have code as follows

```
public class Field<T> 
{

    private T_fieldValue;

    public T FieldValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _fieldValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _fieldValue = value;

        }
    }

}


public class Container
{
    private ObservableCollection<Field> _fieldValues;


    public ObservableCollection<Field> FieldValues
    {

        get { return _fieldValues; }
        set { _fieldValues = value; }
    }
}
```

How can I pass my Type parameter in container class as well ??

i.e I am looking for something like

```
  private ObservableCollection<Field<T>> _fieldValues;
```

**EDIT:**
   I made changes to the class as follows

```
public class Container<T> 
{

    public string MyName { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<Field<T>> _fieldValues;


    public ObservableCollection<Field<T>> FieldValues
    {

        get { return _fieldValues; }
        set { _fieldValues = value;}
    }
}

}
```

Now in my Main class how can i call something like

```
   new ObservableCollection<Container>() { MyName ="Kyle",

   new Container() { FieldValues = new ObservableCollection<Field<int>>()

  {new Field<int>(){FieldValue=10}}; // I am not sure if this syntax is correct
```

Comment: Extract an nongeneric interface?

Comment: `public class Container<T>: BindableBase`

Comment: Is there still a question or has Peter answered it by now ? If so mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the `Container` class generic as well:

```
class Container<T> : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Field<T>> _fieldValues;
}
```

If you always have a specific `T` parameter type in mind for `Container`, then you can of course just hard-code that:

```
class Container : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Field<SomeSpecificType>> _fieldValues;
}
```

To create an instance of your generic `Container<T>` class, you use the exact same syntax you'd use for any generic type. For example, if `T` is `int`, you would use:

```
new Container<int>()
```

Then you can assign the `FieldValues` property as you indicate in your updated example. I.e.:

```
FieldValues = new ObservableCollection<Field<int>>()
```

Comment: But what if my container class has some other non-generic value ?? for eg: lets say my container class contains a 'string' then how can i call it in my mainclass ??

Comment: @kyle you can have more than one generic parameter, it would just be `class Container<T,TOther> : BindableBase` and you would create it as `new Container<SomeSpecificType, string>()`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain can you take a look at my updated question.

Comment: @kyle: I don't understand your question. Your code example doesn't show any `string` or other types. As Scott says, if you intended for `Container` to be generic, you can always just add a parameter. But I'm not really sure that's even what you're asking. Please edit your code example so it clearly shows what you mean.

Comment: @PeterDuniho sorry for that..have updated the question